# JQuery Mobile: center text-align for label in Toggle Bar

Tags: jquery-mobile, toggle, text-align

I created this simple code, It it just a button that stays on a "push" state when clicked and returns to normal when clicked again.

THE PROBLEM:
by using float:right the text in the label goes to right, and if i dont set the float it goes to the left by default. but when I put float:center it stays on the left. If someone can help me put the text on the center I would be happy. thank you!

[This is my code from jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfGmJ/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery Mobile element you want to center is the one nested within your fieldset with the `.ui-btn-text` class:

```
#ui-2 .ui-btn-text {
    text-align : center;
    width      : 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nfGmJ/10/

Comment: thanks for this.. it is working BUT what I am trying to put in center is TCENTER... I noticed that if I want to make the text in the middle I should set the text-align:center, float:right... what I dont understand is why should I make it float to the right first...